# Creating a screenshot image of a website if given nothing other than a url?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Website screenshots using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php)

I was wondering if it is possible to create a screen-shot-like preview of a website if given nothing other than a url?

Comment: what do you mean by if given nothing other than a url??

Comment: if I have a url for example: http://www.google.com I would like to find a way to create a screen shot for the website automatically.... something like: 

<img src="someFunctions('http://www.google.com')" />

Comment: I know how using c#? jquery won't be able to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, you can**, please read the following stackoverflow questions:

[generating-a-screenshot-of-a-website-using-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550947/generating-a-screenshot-of-a-website-using-jquery)

[website-screenshots-using-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php)

There are some tools with the goal of snapshotting the website to an image, so, using Jquery in conjunction with PHP you can achieve your goal!

Comment: these methods did not work for me...

Answer (score 0):

Using only JavaScript/jQuery?  Likely not, as that would violate the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  And even if you could, it's be challenging in JavaScript to make it into an image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service like [BitPixels](http://www.bitpixels.com/) as well. Use JSONP if there are any same origin issues and it should be easy enough.