# Print your webpage screen and send email with printed image

Tags: javascript, screenshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Capture HTML Canvas as gif/jpg/png/pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf)

Is there a simple way to create JS onclick function which will print the current screen of the website, save it as the image (.jpg or something) and send it via email.

I would like to create this option for the user side so there is no need for user to use keyboard 'Prnt Scr', then open Paint and paste and 'save as' an image, then attach and send via email.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: On the regular web (not in a plugin/extension to a browser)? You can use a Java applet I imagine. Maybe `canvas`? I wonder though.

Comment: Well, actually, this is duplicate more than likely.

Comment: All I know is that you can only do this in extensions.

Comment: Sure it qualifies as a duplicate? This question also asks how to then send the image in an email. +1 Fairly common use case and a good question I think.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few solutions out there:

- Converting a webpage to an image using `wkhtmltox`:

  [generating a screenshot of a website using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4550947/352449)
- Make use of the `HTMLCanvasElement` object's `toDataURL` function:

  [How to take screen shot of a div with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6887183/352449)
- The `html2canvas` script:

  [Using HTML5/Canvas/Javascript to take screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4912092/352449)
- Using the PHP `wkhtmltoimage`:

  [Taking screenshots of websites in PHP](http://www.codediesel.com/php/taking-screenshots-of-websites-in-php/)

---

**ps:** a simple [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?hl=pt&client=ubuntu&hs=w6&channel=fs&q=jquery%20take%20screenshot%20page&oq=jquery%20take%20screenshot%20page&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=serp.3...0.0.0.256821.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0.ZHlBUOEzXWo) gives you all of this!

Comment: [Embrace the non-Googlers.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers) It's like turn the other cheek for geeks.

Comment: @JaredFarrish, Agreed, but Embrace the stackoverflow [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) :)

Comment: Well... I see that I'm still the only one who has voted to close as duplicate. I think I know the FAQ by now. `;)`

Comment: @JaredFarrish, forgot about that, it is done! (was distracted commenting) :)

Comment: Thank you anyway for replying and pointing to the right thread

Comment: didn't answer how to send the email part. Also, in response to "ps: a simple Google search gives you all of this!", the google search often takes you to many different SO answers as the first hits so these questions are good questions pal.