# Generate a png or jpeg image of a webpage using some java jar

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, grails

I have a Java EE application running and on one of its webpage, I want to add a functionality that whenever the user presses a certain button, I get an image of ONLY the webpage which is currently displayed on the user end.

I have tried using a library for the purpose http://code.google.com/p/java-html2image/wiki/HtmlImageGenerator

My code using the above library is:

```
HtmlImageGenerator imageGenerator = new HtmlImageGenerator();
    imageGenerator.loadUrl("http://localhost:8080/scheduler/xxx")
    imageGenerator.getLinks();
    imageGenerator.saveAsImage("sos.png");
```

It does generate an image but my page contains a lot of css and colors but the image which is generated does not seem to add that color and infact produces a blue screen with almost no css applied.

Can someone help in the code or suggest any alternative libraries for the same?

Answer (score 0):

How about using jQuery or java script, on googling a bit I found the following two existing posts in stackoverflow

[generating a screenshot of a website using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550947/generating-a-screenshot-of-a-website-using-jquery)

[Take a screenshot of a webpage with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript)

Comment: I googled quiet a bit but the above solutions take the screenshot of the entire webpage which is not my requirement.