# Take a Screen Shot with the help of JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webpage-screenshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [generating a screenshot of a website using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550947/generating-a-screenshot-of-a-website-using-jquery)
>   [How to take screen shot of a div with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887183/how-to-take-screen-shot-of-a-div-with-javascript)

i Want take a screen shot of entire web page using JavaScript or jQuery, and also set that image another window background on click of button.
how can i achieve it.

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots/6678156#6678156 should help

Comment: You cant do this using JavaScript. Perhaps another technology like flash or a java applet but I dont have much experience with these. Alternatively you could look at using a PHP library.