# jQuery plugin for rich status messages

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Is there any plugin that exists for taking user input and adding a rich text feel to it. For example, a user posts a status containing a link to a video, image, or webpage.

Is there a jQuery plugin that will recognize the link, discern content type, and then wrap it in the appropriate parent elements? I know I could build it in jQuery myself, it just seems so ubiquitous I thought I should try leaving it to the experts.

If there are any plugins for this, listing them would be super helpful. Couldn't find any on google. Thanks!

Comment: Most of that uses Ajax to get at the content and show the first frame or a thumbnail

Comment: Ya I know, I was just wondering if there is a plugin for it, or if I have to write it myself.

Comment: But you will need a backend support so a plugin is not enough http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550947/generating-a-screenshot-of-a-website-using-jquery

Answer (score 1):

There are so many rich text editor available including open source. I just googled few:

[10-excellent-free-rich-text-editors](http://www.jquery4u.com/tools/10-excellent-free-rich-text-editors/)

[LIGHTWEIGHT RICH TEXT EDITOR](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/lwRTE)

[20-excellent-free-rich-text-editors](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2008/12/20-excellent-free-rich-text-editors/)

Also check few related questions:
[looking-for-a-rich-text-editor-that-is-simple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674609/looking-for-a-rich-text-editor-that-is-simple)

I used markedit and nicedit light weight but doesn't provide video functionality.

These plugins will give you facility to add rich text, but while saving you have to save the complete html markup and fetch it as it is.

Comment: Rhual, not a rich text editor, I was hoping for more of a text parser that can translate user generated content into a nicer format automatically

Comment: not sure exactly what you are looking for...but with rich text editors, you can add videos, images, links, etc....are you not looking for something like stackoverflow uses for answers and questions?

Comment: Well as nice as rich text editors are, I was hoping I could find something that doesn't bulk things up GUI wise, and hides complexity from the users. Something like an open source library that I could use to achieve custom results.